# MVC - Load [HttpPost] view into Jquery/Ajax modal window

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

The way my code works currently is when a button is pressed variables are passed and Jquery unhides a modal window and makes an AJAX call to get the [HttpGet] portion of my Controller Action.  This loads a form in the modal window.  The modal has a save and cancel button, when the save button is pressed the form is submitted with ajaxSubmit.  On successful save something is saved to the database, then a url is created and passed back to jquery and user is redirected with window.location.href.

What I'd like to have happen is when the save button is pressed the [HttpPost] part of controller action will make some logic choices, and if a certain condition is met within the action then return PartialView(model) is returned back to the modal window with an error message or pop up so that the user doesn't have to retype their information and understands why the save didn't go through and can edit quickly and try save again.

The Jquery:

```
var createNewClaimSetup = function () {

    $(selectors.btnCreateNewClaim).live('click', function () {

        var serialNumber = $(this).attr(attributes.serialNumber);
        var spaRegistrationId = $(this).attr(attributes.spaRegistrationId);
        var customerNumber = $(this).attr(attributes.customerNumber);
        var customerStatementName = $(this).attr(attributes.customerStatementName);

        $(selectors.serialNumberHidden).val(serialNumber);
        $(selectors.spaRegistationIdHidden).val(spaRegistrationId);
        $(selectors.customerNumberHidden).val(customerNumber);
        $(selectors.customerStatementName).val(customerStatementName);

        $(selectors.dialog).attr(attributes.title, 'Create New Claim');

        $.ajax ({
            url: inputs.warrantyClaimCreateUrl,
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                   serialNumber: serialNumber,
                   customerNumber: customerNumber
                },
             cache: false,
             success: function (result) {
                $(selectors.dialog).html(result.toString());
                $(selectors.dialog).dialog ({
                     resizable: false,
                    height: 600,
                    width: 850,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        'Save': function () {
                        // check to see if a value has been entered for problem description before submitting form
                        //
                        if(!$('#AddProblemModel_ProblemDesc').val().length==0 && (!$('#ClaimPrefix').val().length==0 || $('#chkManualClaimNum').is(':checked')))
                            $(selectors.createNewClaimForm).ajaxSubmit({
                                cache: false,
                                success: function (data) {
                                      if (data.length == 0) {
                                        location.reload();
                                        $(selectors.dialog).dialog('close');
                                    } else {
                                        $(selectors.dialog).dialog('close');
                                        window.location.href = data.redirectToUrl;
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                            else{
                                return alert('You must select a prefix and enter a description for the problem before saving');
                            }
                        },
                        Cancel: function () {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                      }
                    });
                }

             });

        });
}
```

Controller Action GET (edited for brevity):

```
public virtual ActionResult WarrantyClaimCreateNew(string serialNumber, string customerNumber, string customerStatementName)
    {
        WarrantyClaimModel model = wcs.CreateNewClaimInfo(serialNumber, customerNumber, false);

        ViewBag.InvalidPrefix = false;
        ViewBag.DupeWaNum = false;
        return View(model);
    }
```

Controller Action POST (edited for brevity):

```
[HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult WarrantyClaimCreateNew(WarrantyClaimCreateNewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            WaNumberDupeModel WAdupe = new WaNumberDupeModel(model.WarrantyClaimNumber);
            // Rebuild WarrantyClaimModel object to pass back to view
            WarrantyClaimModel model2 = wcs.CreateNewClaimInfo(model.SerialNumber, model.CustomerNumber, false);

            // check if prefix is valid
            if (WAdupe.DupeType == WaDupeType.InvalidPrefix)
            {
                ViewBag.InvalidPrefix = true;
                return PartialView(model2);
                //return Json(new { Url = Url.Action("WarrantyClaimCreateNew", model2) });
            }
            // check if wa number already exists
            if (WAdupe.DupeExists)
            {
                ViewBag.DupeWaNum = true;
                return PartialView(model2);
            }

            // create/save the new claim
            if (wcs.CreateNewWarrantyClaim(model))
            {
                var redirectString = "WarrantyClaimDetail?warrantyClaimNumber=" + model.WarrantyClaimNumber;

                if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                {
                    return Json(new { redirectToUrl = redirectString }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }

                return RedirectToAction(Actions.WarrantyClaimDetail(newClaimNumber));
            }

            return RedirectToAction(Actions.WarrantyClaimSaveFail());
        }
        else
        {
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Alerts In View If Conditions In Controller Action Met:

```
<%if (ViewBag.InvalidPrefix == true) { %>
        alert("Please choose a valid prefix for your warranty claim number.");
    <% } %>

    <%if (ViewBag.DupeWaNum == true) { %>
        alert("Warranty Claim Number already exists, please choose another manual WA number or try again.");
    <% } %>
```

I haven't even been able to reload the view refreshed in the modal at all, let alone with changed to the bound model intact.

I know that the first part of the AJAX call (type: "GET") uses the URL to go into the controller action GET and gets back the return View(model) then converts it to HTML and sets the modal window HTML to it.  I've been assuming that the ajaxSubmit goes back to the controller and gets the POST version of the action, and that the data part of success: function (data) should be the view return if condition is met and the built JSON URL to redirect to if it's not.

I've tried setting the modal html to data and making sure the controller invalid prefix condition is met, however the content in the modal window never seems to refresh.  I'll also need to figure out how to logically tell in JQUERY if the controller returned a view or a URL through JSON but I don't think that will be hard to figure out.

I've read through a dozen or so mvc jquery ajax modal similar questions and they've helped but not

Thanks for any help shedding some light on how I might accomplish what a want here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of a partial answer to what I was looking for.  I realize now my main stumbling block was to have my test alerts before building the modal window as "return alert(whatever)" which was obviously returning the alert and not running the rest of the code, dumb.

The solution I have working now is a pretty bad hack.  I have it rebuild the modal and attach the POST view data to it.  However this isn't looped so if you save and fail again I've set it to alert the user save failed again and to retry, then the modal closes and they can start again from scratch.

Tomorrow I'll see about turning this into a looping rather than nested structure.

New "working" JQuery code:

```
var createNewClaimSetup = function () {

    $(selectors.btnCreateNewClaim).live('click', function () {

        var serialNumber = $(this).attr(attributes.serialNumber);
        var spaRegistrationId = $(this).attr(attributes.spaRegistrationId);
        var customerNumber = $(this).attr(attributes.customerNumber);
        var customerStatementName = $(this).attr(attributes.customerStatementName);

        $(selectors.serialNumberHidden).val(serialNumber);
        $(selectors.spaRegistationIdHidden).val(spaRegistrationId);
        $(selectors.customerNumberHidden).val(customerNumber);
        $(selectors.customerStatementName).val(customerStatementName);

        $(selectors.dialog).attr(attributes.title, 'Create New Claim');

        $.ajax ({
            url: inputs.warrantyClaimCreateUrl,
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                   serialNumber: serialNumber,
                   customerNumber: customerNumber
                },
             cache: false,
             success: function (result) {
                $(selectors.dialog).html(result.toString());
                $(selectors.dialog).dialog ({
                     resizable: false,
                    height: 600,
                    width: 850,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        'Save': function () {
                        // check to see if a value has been entered for problem description before submitting form
                        //
                        if(!$('#AddProblemModel_ProblemDesc').val().length==0 && (!$('#ClaimPrefix').val().length==0 || $('#chkManualClaimNum').is(':checked')))
                            $(selectors.createNewClaimForm).ajaxSubmit({
                                cache: false,
                                success: function (data) {
                                      if (data.length == 0) {
                                        location.reload();
                                        $(selectors.dialog).dialog('close');
                                    } else if(data.redirectToUrl) {
                                        $(selectors.dialog).dialog('close');
                                        window.location.href = data.redirectToUrl;
                                    } else {
                                        $(selectors.dialog).html(data.toString());
                                        $('#chkManualClaimNum').attr('checked','checked');
                                        $('#manualClaimInfo').toggle();
                                        $(selectors.dialog).dialog ({
                                             resizable: false,
                                            height: 600,
                                            width: 850,
                                            modal: true,
                                            buttons: {
                                                'Save': function () {
                                                    if(!$('#AddProblemModel_ProblemDesc').val().length==0 && (!$('#ClaimPrefix').val().length==0 || $('#chkManualClaimNum').is(':checked')))
                                                    $(selectors.createNewClaimForm).ajaxSubmit({
                                                        cache: false,
                                                        success: function (data) {
                                                              if (data.length == 0) {
                                                                location.reload();
                                                                $(selectors.dialog).dialog('close');
                                                            } else if(data.redirectToUrl) {
                                                                $(selectors.dialog).dialog('close');
                                                                window.location.href = data.redirectToUrl;
                                                            } else {
                                                                alert('Save failed again. Please start over.');
                                                                $(selectors.dialog).dialog('close');
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                                },
                                                Cancel: function () {
                                                    $(this).dialog('close');
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                            else{
                                return alert('You must select a prefix and enter a description for the problem before saving');
                            }
                        },
                        Cancel: function () {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                      }
                    });
                }

             });

        });
}
```

This does at least show how to pass the POST view back to the modal window.